# Calculating PMI for bigram and discrepancy

Tags: python, nltk, information-theory

Suppose I have the following text:

```
text = "this is a foo bar bar black sheep  foo bar bar black sheep foo bar bar black sheep shep bar bar black sentence"
```

I can calculate the PMI for bigram using NLTK as follow:

```
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(word_tokenize(text))
for i in finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.pmi):
    print(i)
```

which gives:

```
(('is', 'a'), 4.523561956057013)
(('this', 'is'), 4.523561956057013)
(('a', 'foo'), 2.938599455335857)
(('sheep', 'shep'), 2.938599455335857)
(('black', 'sentence'), 2.523561956057013)
(('black', 'sheep'), 2.523561956057013)
(('sheep', 'foo'), 2.353636954614701)
(('bar', 'black'), 1.523561956057013)
(('foo', 'bar'), 1.523561956057013)
(('shep', 'bar'), 1.523561956057013)
(('bar', 'bar'), 0.5235619560570131)
```

Now to check my own understanding I want to find the PMI for PMI('black', 'sheep'). PMI formula is given as:

[image: $$ pmi(w1,w2) = \ $$]

There are 4 instances of 'black' in the text, there are 3 instances of 'sheep' in the text and black and sheep come together 3 times, the length of the text is 23. Now following the formula I do:

```
np.log((3/23)/((4/23)*(3/23)))
```

That gives 1.749199854809259 rather than 2.523561956057013. I wonder why is there a discrepancy here? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about PMI, but based on your information, the PMI formula uses a logarithm in base 2 instead of a base e.

From [NumPy's documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html#numpy-log), `numpy.log` is a Natural logarithm in base e, which is not what you want.

The following formula would give you the result of `2.523561956057013`:

```
math.log((3/23)/((4/23)*(3/23)), 2)
```